# Is there a way to run the functions 'str.length' and 'getNumericValue' in this code?

Tags: java

I have the following code and would like to get the two functions mentioned in the title running. They are appearing in color red, which means they are not being recognized. I've imported the library 'import java.lang.*' but it is still not working.

```
import java.lang.*;

public class Practice {

        public boolean isSumEqual(String firstWord, String secondWord, String targetWord) {
            int first, second, i, j,value, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6;
            first = firstWord.length;
            second = secondWord.length;
            value = 0;
            value2 = 0;

            char[] charArray = firstWord.toCharArray();
            char[] charArray2 = secondWord.toCharArray();
            char[] charArray3 = targetWord.toCharArray();



            for(i = 0; i < first; i++)
            {
                value = getNumericValue(charArray[i]);
                value2 = value2 + value;
            }

            for(j = 0; j < second; j++)
            {
                value3 = getNumericValue(charArray2[i]);
                value4 = value4 + value3;
            }


            for(j = 0; j < second; j++)
            {
                value5 = getNumericValue(charArray2[i]);
                value6 = value6 + value5;
            }

            if( (value2 + value4) == value6)
                return true;
            
            return false;

        }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Practice example = new Practice();
        String firstWord = ("aaa");
        String secondWord = ("a");
        String targetWord = ("aab")
        boolean value;;
        value = example.isSumEqual(firstWord, secondWord, targetWord);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `firstWord.length()`, since `length` is a method of string: [JavaDoc String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length())

Comment: For the getNumericValue: it's a static method of the class `Character`, so you do `Character.getNumericValue(...)`

Comment: Advice:  Every Java beginner should learn about the javadocs for the Java standard libraries.  Where to find them.  How to search them.  When to search them.  They should be the first place you look for answers to questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you called this class `Practice`, hence I took your code and improved it by removing duplicated code.

```java
public class Practice {
    public boolean isSumEqual(String firstWord, String secondWord, String targetWord) {
        int valueOfFirstWord = getValueOfWord(firstWord),
            valueOfSecondWord = getValueOfWord(secondWord),
            valueOfThirdWord = getValueOfWord(targetWord);

        return valueOfFirstWord + valueOfSecondWord == valueOfThirdWord;
    }

    private int getValueOfWord(String word) {
        int value = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            value += Character.getNumericValue(word.charAt(i));
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Practice example = new Practice();
        String firstWord = ("aaa");
        String secondWord = ("a");
        String targetWord = ("aab");
        boolean value = example.isSumEqual(firstWord, secondWord, targetWord);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

---

*Others have already posted an answer for you, therefore I'll only display this version for you as a reference.*

Comment: It is always returning 'false' and never true.

Comment: @Daniel Well, that depends on which input values you use.

Comment: I changed the input. "aaa", "a" and "aaa" should be true cause values are "000", "0" and "000" so its equivalent.

Comment: Input: firstWord = "acb", secondWord = "cba", targetWord = "cdb"
Output: true
Explanation:
The numerical value of firstWord is "acb" -> "021" -> 21.
The numerical value of secondWord is "cba" -> "210" -> 210.
The numerical value of targetWord is "cdb" -> "231" -> 231.
We return true because 21 + 210 == 231.

Comment: The letter value of a letter is its position in the alphabet starting from 0 (i.e. 'a' -> 0, 'b' -> 1, 'c' -> 2, etc.).

The numerical value of some string of lowercase English letters s is the concatenation of the letter values of each letter in s, which is then converted into an integer.

For example, if s = "acb", we concatenate each letter's letter value, resulting in "021". After converting it, we get 21.
You are given three strings firstWord, secondWord, and targetWord, each consisting of lowercase English letters 'a' through 'j' inclusive.

Comment: @Daniel If that's the description of your exercise then your implementation does not work. For more information have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)).

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to import `java.lang.*`, it's always imported in each java file by default.
2. `String` doesn't have such field as `length`, but has a method `length()`. So, you should write `str.length()`.
3. To call `getNumericValue()` you should write `Character.getNumericValue()` or add static import: `import static java.lang.Character.getNumericValue`

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, the method `length()` needs to be called with parentheses like this:

```
firstWood.length()
```

The other method `getNumericValue(char ch)` is associated with the `Character` Class, so you use the method like this:

```
value = Character.getNumericValue(charArray[i]);
```